# Change Users with user control

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

**What I am doing:** Multipage'd program that resides in one window

**What I want to do:** I have an authentication feature setup with it I also want to add a "Change User" feature so I don't need to close the program and reopen it again

**Here's my authentication code:**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Dictionary
{
    public partial class Authenticator : UserControl
    {
        public Authenticator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Exit_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Want to Exit?", "Exit",
              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                      == DialogResult.Yes)

            ((Form)this.TopLevelControl).Close();
        }

        private void Login_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\OverL\OneDrive\Documents\Authenticator01.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Permissions from Login Where Username = '" + UsrTxt.Text + "' and Password = '" + PwTxt.Text + "'", con);

            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                Program.MainForm.ShowControl(ControlsEnum.MainHub); 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credentials!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the code where I want my "Change User" event:**

```
namespace Dictionary
{
    public partial class MainHub : UserControl
    {
        public MainHub(string permissions="")                     
        {
            InitializeComponent();       
        }     
        private void changeUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Program.MainForm.ShowControl(ControlsEnum.Authenticator); //This is what i tried, it pretty much switches to the Authenticator interface and all the buttons work, but when i login it would say "invalid credentials"-this deriving from code, so it gets to the Authentication code but for some reason doesn't find the usernames-&passwords 
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the MainHub code, this is so that all the code goes through:**

```
{
    public enum ControlsEnum
    {
        Authenticator,
        MainHub,
        YL_1,
        YL_2

    }

    public partial class ETMainForm : Form
    {

        private IDictionary<ControlsEnum, Control> controls = new Dictionary<ControlsEnum, Control>();

        public ETMainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ShowControl(ControlsEnum.Authenticator);                                     
        }


        public void ShowControl(ControlsEnum ctrl)
        {
            Control new_ctrl = null;

            if (controls.ContainsKey(ctrl))
            {
                new_ctrl = controls[ctrl];
            }
            else
            {
                new_ctrl = CreateControl(ctrl);
                controls[ctrl] = new_ctrl;
            }

            new_ctrl.Parent = this;
            new_ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            new_ctrl.BringToFront();
            new_ctrl.Show();
        }

        private Control CreateControl(ControlsEnum ctrl)
        {
            switch (ctrl)
            {
                case ControlsEnum.Authenticator:
                    return new Authenticator();
                case ControlsEnum.MainHub:
                    return new MainHub();
                case ControlsEnum.YL_1:
                    return new YL_1();
                case ControlsEnum.YL_2:
                    return new YL_2();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why does the code I implemented not find the right credentials *`Program.MainForm.ShowControl(ControlsEnum.Authenticator);`* and how to fix it

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Updated, the question is why does the code I implemented not find the right credentials *"Program.MainForm.ShowControl(ControlsEnum.Authenticator);"* and how to fix it